# SQL Fiddle moved to SO Data?

Tags: sql

This question is totally unacceptable and will be closed but...

Has SQL Fiddle been amalgameted into Stack Exchange? For example in [HERE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79951/pagining-in-sql-server)

Also - [THIS](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag) is crazy - Am I correct in saying this is sql that is querying SO itself?

(... can't wait to play.)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question, just in the wrong place my dear friend. Probably something for Meta. However, I agree, looks cool.

Comment: can I move it to Meta without having to re-write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, such questions should rather be in meta.

Second, the data explorer has been around for some time now; it's not about executing arbitrary SQL code but for queries against the SO database.

See meta for more questions around the data explorer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer

Comment: the example that I linked to isn't a query against the SO db ... it is an arbitrary script; was that a misuse of the site?

Comment: @whytheq: Kind of, yes - in contrast to SQL Fiddle you cannot create a proper schema (that is, you cannot run [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) statements). The sample shown does only create a table variable and is is therefore not DDL, but just [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language).